# Change Button Color programmatically

Tags: android, button, colors

I have some Buttons in my App at different places. I want to color them according to the location they are in. (Blue Button in Fragment1, Red Button in Fragment2)

I already tried ColorFilter, but that doesn't work with API < 21. I know it is possible to create xml for that, but I don't want to create one for every section in my App. Is it possible to create somehow Backgroud Drawables, which have the color I specify and have the Button animations? (Ripple and selector for API < 21)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
**
 * Sets the color of a button.
 * @param button The Button which should be colored.
 * @param color The color as a already retrieved value.
 */
public static void setButtonColor(Button button, int color) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        //calculate darker color
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
        hsv[2] *= 0.8f;
        int darkColor = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);

        StateListDrawable listDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
        GradientDrawable standard = new GradientDrawable();
        GradientDrawable pressed = new GradientDrawable();

        standard.setColor(color);
        standard.setCornerRadius(3);
        pressed.setColor(darkColor);
        pressed.setCornerRadius(3);

        listDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, pressed);
        listDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, pressed);
        listDrawable.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, standard);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            //noinspection deprecation
            button.setBackgroundDrawable(listDrawable);
        } else {
            button.setBackground(listDrawable);
        }
    } else {
        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the best selection, but it works.